# powershell cant invoke nuget.exe command

Tags: powershell, nuget

I have a powershell script which checks if nuget.exe exists, and runs 'nuget help'

```
# Check if NuGet.exe is available.
if (-not (Get-Command "NuGet.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) 
{ 
    Write-Host "ERROR: NuGet.exe is not available. Install NuGet.exe and add to PATH or copy NuGet.exe into C:\Windows."
    exit
}
Write-Host "Confirmed NuGet.exe is in the path."

# run nuget command
$result = Invoke-Executable NuGet.exe "help"

Write-Host "result = $result"
```

if I run the script, I get an error when running the nuget.exe command, even though it says nuget.exe was found:

```
Confirmed NuGet.exe is in the path.
Invoke-Executable : The term 'Invoke-Executable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\repos\xdcr-nuget\packaging and publishing\auto.ps1:9 char:11
+ $result = Invoke-Executable NuGet.exe "help"
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Executable:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
result =
```

outside of my script, just from the powershell command line I can run nuget commands such as `nuget help` perfectly fine. but the powershell script is unable to run any nuget command without this error, am i doing something wrong with how I setup my powershell script?

Comment: Take a closer look at the actual error. What's `Invoke-Executable` supposed to be, and why do you think you need that instead of just directly invoking `NuGet.exe`?

Comment: if i try to run nuget commands without `Invoke-Executable` then including multiple args doesn't work. Adding `$result = NuGet.exe "pack -Version 2.1.1"` to my script will result in an error `Unknown command: 'pack -Version 2.1.1'` even though running `$nuget pack -Version 2.1.1` from the command line works fine.  powershell only works with one arg such as ` $result = NuGet.exe "pack"` if im not using Invoke-Executable

Comment: It gives an error because adding quotes makes it pass the thing as one single parameter. `$result = NuGet.exe pack -Version 2.1.1` (no quotes anywhere) should simply work. A useful trick for when PowerShell *does* interfere with parsing is to use `--%` (stop parsing), so `$result = NuGet.exe --% pack -Version 2.1.1` to pass the whole thing as-is, even though there should be no need for that in this case. In any case, the error is telling you what's wrong: it's not anything to do with NuGet but the fact that the `Invoke-Executable` cmdlet isn't defined (this is not standard).